# How to use mysql find_in_set function in querydsl?

Tags: jpa, querydsl

`Expressions.booleanTemplate("FIND_IN_SET({0}, {1})", path, param)`

It doesn't working.

It cause

```java
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 3, column 18 [select task
from com.simple.entity.Task task
where FIND_IN_SET(task.parentIds, ?1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Expressions.booleanTemplate("FIND_IN_SET({0}, {1})>0", path, param)